# couchbase document size limit, is storing generic data preferable

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, couchbase, dao

Say I have a couchbase document that is sized 12 MB (Actual size, not size on disk). Couchbase literature says there is a sizing limitation of 20 MB on documents' actual size. 
If I were to have a significant part as generic data on this document (6 MB out of 12 MB). Suggest me which is a better approach from below.

- Drop the generic data altogether from the document and build it myself after database operation and append it to  the response object that gets sent to UI layer. Again drop any generic data received from UI while upserting back to database.
- Let the current document structure stay as is. Fetch and Upsert back the entire 12 MB data each time.

If I were to adopt the first approach, I will have to create a service that builds 6 MB data by iterating with  a sychronous change. I will have to call this service everytime during the database operation for this document. Is this going to be an overhead, or, will it reduce the time for the whole operation compared to fetching a 12 MB document?

Comment: Is the "generic data" different for every document, or the same for all?

Comment: Attributes are same, and values can be generated by repeated iteration with a synchronous change starting from some data that is always available in the document. But when I am saying generic, I am saying that this information can be constructed from the actual impacting data stored to database.